# UITableview show different data based on cell selected

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

In the app I'm designing, here is what I'm trying to achieve:

1. A main view, which only have 3 items, "to-do", "shopping list", "note".
2. A detail view, based on the item selected in the main view, display different set of data.  This is a UITableView.
3. The transition from the main view to detail view is using segue, more like the main view is a front view, once an item is selected, a segue is called to transit to the detail UITableView.

My questions are:

1. For the main view, should I use UITableView with only 3 cells and disable scrolling? or should I use a UIView with 3 buttons?
2. How can I display different set of data in the detail view, based on the selection in the main view?  eg. if the user selected "todo", then the detail view should display a to-do list; if the use selected "shopping list", then display the data from shopping list.

An example or a link is much appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
I plan to use NSUserDefault for storing the data, since to-do list and shopping list are relatively very light weight.  In the future, if needed, I'll consider using `firebase` or `iCloud`for backup and syncing purpose.

Comment: Please show the code you have written, and what the problem is you are having with it. Please see [Ask]

Comment: you could use a segment control - https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisegmentedcontrol. the rest you would likely need to look at using a database backend like core data or realm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](https://guides.codepath.com/ios/Using-UITableView) is a solution I found that solves my question.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1:  You could do either, but it would be easier to just make a `UIView` with 3 buttons.
Question 2: The best way to accomplish this is with the `present segue`.  Make 3 `UITableViewController` to be your detail views for the 3 buttons in the main view.  Then drag from each button to its respective `tableViewController` and select `present`.  Give each `segue` an identity.  Then, in your main view, in `prepareForSegue`, make three `if statements` checking for if the `segue.identifier == "buttonSegueIdentifier"`.  In each if statements, perform the necessary tasks.  Finally, when each button is clicked, call `prepareForSegue`.

Comment: This is the correct answer, but I think breaking it out into some actual code blocks might help OP.

Answer (score 1):

Question 1: As Gabe said, you could do either, but it's probably simpiler to just use three buttons.

Question 2: The best way to handle view controllers displaying different data is to have different view controllers. Use one view controller for each category you have. Use a navigation controller to create the transitions between view controllers. From the buttons to the detail views, create `show` segues. Consider a storyboard set up like this:

[image]